# Ambiguity between 'Resource.ResourceMan' and 'Resource.resourceMan' between 'Resource.resourceCulture' and resource.resourceCulture, etc

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an asp.net mvc project which above all includes a folder called Language which contains a folder called LayoutEmpty in which I have 3 Resource Files: Resource.sq.resx, Resource.resx and Resource.en.resx . There is another project folder which contains inside the Resource.Designer.cs another resourceMan object reference and the project itself has 3 Resource Files. I don't know what leads the compiler to ambiguity. Anybody any helpful ideas?

```
    I have tried to fix this issue by changing the Access Modifiers of the Resource Files but however no success achieved.

    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", "15.0.0.0")]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]       [global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
public class Resource {

            private static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager resourceMan;

            private static global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo resourceCulture;

            [global::System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1811:AvoidUncalledPrivateCode")]
internal Resource() {
}

/// <summary>
///   Returns the cached ResourceManager instance used by this class.
/// </summary>
            [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
public static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {
get {
   if (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null)) {
        global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("ProjectName.Language.LayoutEmpty.Resource", typeof(Resource).Assembly);
        resourceMan = temp;
    }
    return resourceMan;
}
}

/// <summary>
///   Overrides the current thread's CurrentUICulture property for all
///   resource lookups using this strongly typed resource class.
/// </summary>
            [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
public static global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo Culture {
get {
      return resourceCulture;
    }
set {
      resourceCulture = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There will be 2 resources files under Properties.Resources with name as Resources.designer.cs and Resources3.designer.cs.
Delete the one with name Resources3 as it will be sometimes added automatically and Rebuild the solution. Also, if the errors are still shown, restart your VS.

Comment: Thanks - I had Resources - copy.resx. Grrr.